# How to "attach debugger" to WPF window button?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

edit:
*I don't have source code, and someone says that one would [need to have debug files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222456/enable-and-disable-step-into-debugging-on-certain-project-in-a-visual-studio-s) to step in. So, I don't know it's true or not,so I will still ask this question*

---

In VS, I am trying to `Attach To Process` to external application to find out, what method (with parameters) is fired on specific button-click.

[Per this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775894/getting-the-debugger-to-break-at-the-next-click-event), before I click button, i pause execution and click make "Step In", however, button click is not being caught.

Video: https://files.fm/u/2wf4gjxb
(neither checking `Enable just my code` option helps, not unchecking it. Also, it doesn't have any pdb([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvPJz.png)), so i assume it is being considered as external code)

Afaik, the window should be WPF (but someone in comment said, it look slike WinForms). Even WinSpy (or alike) programs are unable to detect buttons when I try to inspect the elements on that window. What should I try?

Comment: @Crowcoder well, i don't know how to do that ( i am a bit new to the VS debugging), specifically i dont know how to find out button-event handler at all. that is external app i dont have any source-code.

Comment: The Window does not look a WPF window at all... It’s WinForms.

Comment: Yes because WPF is direct2D and does not use handles for every control.

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 I've updated my question to answer your question. so, you can delete the comment now safely. If i have to post further information, let me know... thanks

Comment: If it’s WPF you can use snoop https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=snoopwpf to check the button for its binded command or click event.

Comment: @T.Todua if it does not solve your problem then there is no reason to upvote. Try it first... If it helped you, buy me a beer.

Comment: @LegacyCode well, i am getting the exception when i tried that program:  `Unhandled Expection: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`. btw, even though upvotes/answer-marks work here , i will do what you want and buy a beer ; )

Answer (score 1):

You could first try to decompile the code you are trying to debug:  This can be done at low level with ILSpy ( open source).  But there is an extention for ILSpy in Visual studio. I would suggest you take a look at the following  link from Microsoft about how to go about  debugging third party assemblies:  [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/decompilation?view=vs-2019)

As suggested by @Legacy Code , you could go for the easier to use decompiler: [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy).  You can attach to a process there to and have the code be decompiled.

If the creator added some attributes to block this, it get's a lot harder fast.
Recompiling the decompiled code yourself and using those assemblies and such...

Comment: Don’t use ILSpy... Use dnSpy https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy

Comment: Thanks for the tip, hadn't heard about that  one,  it still uses ILSpy underneath I see and it doesn't have VS ihtegration  that I can find?

Comment: I don’t think it uses ILSpy underneath. I think it uses Roslyn. dnSpy itself can be installed as VS extension.

Comment: Ah I see ... I just read... It uses ILSpy to decompile and Roslyn to compile.

Comment: Thanks for answers, unfortunately, the app is protected and can't be decompiled : /

Comment: @T.ToduaThats impossible. All .NET applications can be decompiled.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool. If it is indeed a .NET application, you will see method calls with parameters on the button click.

Comment: Please mention in your answer that you are the one that made Runtime Flow.

Comment: @NotAPro Well, it says "my Runtime Flow".

Comment: Fair enough, my bad: didn't see that lol.